# Draw CGImage in UITableView

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgimage

So, I have a custom cell and I need to draw all images as CGImage in tableView, but I can't get it working. I have created a test project and tested the code with simple views. Everything worked perfect, and when I copypasted the same code to my custom cell it stopped working. Here is the code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

    UIImage *karmaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"karma.png"];
    [self drawImage:karmaImage withRect:CGRectMake(boundsX + 255, 16, 14, 14)];
}
-(void)drawImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageRetain(image.CGImage);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple recommends to add your custom view to the UITableViewCell's contentView instead of changing UITableViewCell itself.  See [TimeZoneCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Listings/5_CustomTableViewCell_Classes_TimeZoneCell_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-5_CustomTableViewCell_Classes_TimeZoneCell_m-DontLinkElementID_40) for an example.

Comment: +1 You should never try to override the drawing for `UITableViewCell` itself. You will break all kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawRect method, you should probably call [super drawRect:rect];

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was that contentView of the cell with custom background color was hiding the image. Here is the right code:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:(232.0/255.0) green:(232.0/255.0) blue:(232.0/255.0) alpha:1.0].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *karmaImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"karma.png"]; 
    [self drawImage:karmaImg withContext:context atPoint:CGPointMake(boundsX + 255, 16)];
}


-(void)drawImage:(UIImage *)image withContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    if(image) {
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Image failed to load.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious; why not just draw the image onto a uiImageView once when you create the cell (or even just once for all cells) and add that to the contentView, rather than reloading/drawing it every time a cell appears. That would seem cleaner and faster.